# String to char[] empty?

Tags: c++

I have done some extensive searching but not come across something that works for me so I apologise.

```
char Name[20];

string transferfile;
ifstream file("file.txt");

while (file)
{
    getline(file, transferstring, ',');
    memcpy(Name, transferString.c_str(), sizeof(transferString));
    cout << Name << endl;
}
```

While this compiles fine it gives me nothing in Name. I have tried a few other ways and still had no luck. The correct data is being put into transferstring as a 'cout << transferstring;' prints the correct data.

Anybody have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: `sizeof(transferString)` is not the same as `transferString.length()` (which is what you are looking for).

Comment: You should also check if opening file succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `sizeof` is incorrect. That just tells you the size of the object that holds the string. But you need the length of the string, plus one for the null-terminator. You should instead write:

```
memcpy(Name, transferString.c_str(), transferString.size()+1);
```

whilst noting that your code is a buffer overrun just waiting to happen. You'll want to defend against that in your real code.

I'd also add the usual comment that, since this is C++, you would expect to use `std::copy` rather than `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `transferString` is a `std::string` - in that case, instead of `sizeof`, use `transferString.size()`.

You might also need to add another `\0` character at the end then.

Anyway, what you are doing here is rather dangerous, and I would avoid using C arrays at all if possible.

Comment: Thanks that sorted it

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems with your code:

- you attempt to use sizeof on a std::string (as pointed out by the other answers)
- you use memcpy in C++ (consider std::copy with iterators as an alternative); You also attempt to copy the size of the read data into a `char[20]`. If data in your file contains a string longer than 20 before your first ',' character, you will create a buffer overflow.
- you do not check the result of the read operation, before copying the value.

Your code should/could be:

```
while ( getline(file, transferstring, ',') ) // check the state of 
                                             // the stream after getline
{
    cout << transferString << endl;
}
```

If you want to copy into the name, use one of these:

```
char *name = nullptr;
while ( getline(file, transferstring, ',') )
{
    name = new char[transferstring.size() + 1];
    std::copy(transferstring.begin(), transferstring.end(), name);
    name[transferstring.size()] = 0;
}
// somewhere later:
delete []name;
```

or:

```
char name[20];
while ( getline(file, transferstring, ',') )
{
    std::size_t size = std::min(transferstring.size(), 19);
    std::copy_n(transferstring.begin(), size, name); // copy at most 19 characters
    name[size] = 0;
}
```

My choice though would be to not use char array at all and keep the value in a std::string.

Answer (score 0):

```
//an alternative way when stl isn't working
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char Name[20];

        string transferfile;
        ifstream in("file.txt");

        while (!(in.eof()))//read till the end of the file
        {
            in>>transferfile;
                if(!in.eof())
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<transferfile.length();i++)//copy al the letters from the string
                {
                    Name[i] = transferfile[i];
                }
                for(int i=0;i<transferfile.length();i++)//print the array 
                {
                    cout<<Name[i];
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining this